# INSERT INTO using PDO not inserting data

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to get the data to insert into the specified database but it just wont. Ive looked at the manual tried examples and all of that but I cant get the data to pass through to the database I can however echo/print_r/var_dump it so I know I have data. Here is my code:

```
public function insertJson($url, $subId)
    {

        $json_file = file_get_contents(KHAN_BASE.$url.'/videos');
        if(isset($json_file))
        {
            $json_decoded = json_decode($json_file, true);
        }else{
            $this->error = 'A valid JSON file was not specified';
        }

       // var_dump($json_decoded); <--- This return all of the data needed from the json pull so i know I have data

        //m3u8, mp4, png,
        //". $row['m3u8'] .",". $row['mp4'] .",". $row['png'] .",
        foreach($json_decoded as $row)
        {
            //echo $row['backup_timestamp'].'<br/>';  <--- This outputs the correct information so I know I can access it that way

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_khan_videos (sub_subject_id, backup_timestamp, date_added, description,
            duration, extra_properties, has_questions, ka_url, keywords, kind, position, readable_id, relative_url, title, url, views, 
            youtube_id) VALUES (:subid, :backup_timestamp, :date_added, :description, :duration, :extra_properties, :has_questions, :ka_url, :keywords, :kind, :position,
            :readable_id, :relative_url, :title, :url, :views, :youtube_id)";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindValue(":subid", $subId);
                $stmt->bindValue(":backup_timestamp",  $row['backup_timestamp']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":date_added", $row['date_added']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":description", $row['description']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":duration", $row['duration']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":extra_properties", $row['extra_properties']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":has_questions", $row['has_questions']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":ka_url", $row['ka_url']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":keywords", $row['keywords']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":kind", $row['kind']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":position", $row['position']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":readable_id", $row['readable_id']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":relative_url", $row['relative_url']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":title", $row['title']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":url", $row['url']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":views", $row['views']);
                $stmt->bindValue(":youtube_id", $row['youtube_id']); 
            $stmt->execute();

        }  
    }
```

Im not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried binding it as an array (ex: `$array = array(':subId' => $subId); $stmt->execute($array);`) and still get no data through to the database. I know my config for the `$this->db` is good because I can pull other forms of already populated data with it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the insert statement manually into `mysql` to check for a syntax or naming error? What do your PHP error logs say? Also I am pretty sure you want to `prepare` the statement before the loop (for efficiency purposes) but this shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: I am getting no errors in the log and I do have logging on. There is no indication as to the MySQL syntax being wrong because if I add quotes around the :placeholder it inserts perfectly fine from PHPMyAdmin. Also as stated in the code I can echo a variable using the $row['name'] setup so i know that I have information being stored in my variables.

Comment: Couple of things.  You don't need to prepare the statement every time around the loop!  Doing so would impact the loop's speed quite significantly.  Prepare the statement before entering the loop and just reuse it each time round, that's supposed to be one of the benefits of prepared statements.  Also, you're not doing any apparent error checking during the SQL part of your code.  prepare, bind and execute all emit false or throw exceptions (depending on mode) if an error occurs.  If this happens you then need to check what went wrong with errorCode and errorInfo

Comment: Thank you very much going to go ahead and do that now see what I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem through some of the advice on here. What had been happening is I was trying to bind null values so the bindValue would cause the execute to go through without producing an error. Simple fix was doing this through foreach loops with a couple if statements which allowed me to set a value to the fields that were null. This solved the error. Again thank you to those who attempted to set in the correct path to finding the solution.